# AngularDart - Dynamically add component into another

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am very new to dart and am trying to inject a component into a parent component just like I have done before in angular 5. However, nothing is being rendered and attached to the DOM. Here is a service I am injecting into the parent component to try to add dynamically add the child component on the fly.

I am using the latest Dart 2.0 sdk too. There are no runtime errors either. It executes and doesn't add anything to the dom.

```
@Injectable()
class ComponentService {
  ViewContainerRef _rootViewContainer;
  ComponentResolver _componentResolver;

  ComponentService(this._componentResolver);

  setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    _rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
  }

  addComponent() {
    final factory =
    _componentResolver.resolveComponentSync(MyCustomComponent);
    final component = 
    factory.create(_rootViewContainer.parentInjector);
    _rootViewContainer.clear();
    _rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView);
   }
}
```

Component to inject dynamically

```
@Component(
selector: 'my-custom-component',
template: '<h1>My Component Details></h1>')
class MyCustomComponent implements OnInit {

  MyCustomComponent();

  @override
  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {}
}
```

As an example of how I am using it.

```
@Component(
selector: 'side-panel',
template: '''<div class="pt-12" #dynamic>

            </div>''',
directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
providers: const [ComponentService])
class SidePanelComponent implements OnInit {

 ViewContainerRef _viewContainerRef;
 get viewContainerRef=>_viewContainerRef;
 @ViewChild('dynamic', read: ViewContainerRef)
 set viewContainerRef(val)=> _viewContainerRef = val;

 ComponentService _componentService;

 SidePanelComponent(this._componentService);

 @override
 Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
  _componentService.setRootViewContainerRef(_viewContainerRef);
  _sideNavHelperService.getSidenav('quick-panel').toggle();
 }
}
```

Comment: could you try `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Thank you, Günter! That fixed my issue. I also was directed towards using the ComponentLoader which worked as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is still up-to-date https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/doc/component_loading.md

Comment: However, I have a funky case were this component is being used in a route. This component is already being used in my root layout component attached to a sidebar. As have seen in Angular 5 before the component will render appropriately in the sidebar component that is part of the root component. 

Now using this the SidePanelComponent is not only rendered at the root level but also injected into the dom at the router-outlet that the route is listening to and not in the sidebar at the root level.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. What does "but also injected into the dom at the router-outlet" mean? Does the sidebar component also contain a `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: I'm using routes to sometimes interact with components rather using a CtreamController, so, that I can save state and show and hide components based on the url.

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to ask another stack question, so, I can explain it in-depth. Thank you for your quick responses!